# what's the difference between /dev/hdc, /dev/sr0, /dev/cdrom

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

I created 2 virtual machines with VMware Workstation 7. They have identical hardwares. One guest is CentOS 5.6, another is Mandriva 2011.
When I try to mount the cdrom in guest OS, in CentOS, I should execute

```
mount /dev/hdc /path/to/mount
```

in Mandriva, I should execute

```
mount /dev/sr0 /path/to/mount
```

I also remebered in some other Linux variant, I had to use

```
mount /dev/cdrom /path/to/mount
```

My questions are:

1. What's the difference between hdc, sr0 or cdrom?
2. Is there a consistent way to mount cdrom in all Linux variants?

Comment: You can read the definition here: https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition-Mass-Storage-Definitions-Naming-HOWTO/x99.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
/dev/hdc
```

is the third IDE hard drive - Secondary Master.

```
/dev/sr0
```

is the first SCSI CD-ROM device in the system.  This may be misleading as SCSI and SATA are interchangeable in Linux terminology.  There is also SCSI emulation of ATAPI devices in some Unix systems (in FreeBSD it's called ATAPICAM) which makes ATAPI CD-ROM devices appear to be SCSI.  Some older software is written purely to interface with SCSI peripherals and can't work with ATAPI ones, so this emulation layer can be quite useful.

```
/dev/cdrom
```

And yes, that is a symlink to one of the above - either done manually with `ln` or through the `udev` configuration.

Answer (score 9):

`/dev/hdc` is a device on the ide controller.

`/dev/sr0` is a device on the scsi controller.

`/dev/cdrom` is a symlink to either `/dev/sr0` or `/dev/hdc` or whichever block device is appropriate.  Most distributions come with a script that automatically sets up `/dev/cdrom` to be the correct device.  So you're generally safe using `/dev/cdrom`.  If you don't have `/dev/cdrom` you can always set it up yourself with `ln -s`

Comment: Thanks, but I double checked my virtual machine's devices. Both type are IDE. At least in Workstation's devices list, both are identified as "CD/DVD (IDE)".

Comment: If you don't believe me then check dmesg.  For sr0 you should see something like: 

    [2.995168] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0

In newer kernel versions they changed the controllers and the drivers around so that more stuff would sit on SCSI.  So even if you have the same hardware, a different kernel can do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The `/dev/hdc` is the older name for IDE CDROM (usually configured in hardware as the third IDE device). Old kernels and user space that use the IDE driver will show it as that. Newer kernels and userspace tools use libata, and map everything to scsi-like devices. So `/dev/sr0` is now the first scsi-rom (zero). `/dev/cdrom` is usually a symlink to the first CD-ROM device.